# routing error in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

routing problem arises when validation errors are updated.
I want

```
Started POST **"/employees/new"** for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-06 14:07:23 +0530 Processing by EmployeesController#create as HTML
```

but I get,

```
 Started POST **"/employees"** for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-06 14:07:23 +0530 Processing by EmployeesController#create as HTML
```

How can I get route employees/new.This occurs, when I correct the validation error.

```
resources :employees
 get 'new' => 'employee#new'
 get 'create' => 'employee#create'
 get 'index' => 'employee#index'
```

and _controller/create method,

```
if @employee.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to action: "index"}
    end
  else
     render 'new'
  end
```

If this solved, there is no data save, it becomes ROLLBACK.

Comment: please, show me your `routes.rb` and your file `_controller.rb`

Comment: I update my question with code.

Comment: The post you're getting is correct. If it can't save it will render `new` but it will still have that post beforehand. Post the whole log entry for the request+response for more help.

Comment: @Matt..Thanks.and sorry I cant get idea.Please give some example.You are correct, but I dont know how to execute further move.bcoz I am very new to rails.

Comment: why dropdown doesnot work with render new method, there rollback occurs while saving data.

Comment: You can remove all the `get` routes that you have added as it already gets defined once you write `resources :employees`. And `'get' create` is the main issue why you are seeing routing error, as it should be `'post' create`.

Comment: @Sahil I got dropdown error.when new employee created, there some validation error. while correcting that dropdown does not listed out. so the value of the id are empty. this also cause the save error. How can I overcome this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try pluralising in your routes like so.

`resources :employees, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :index]`

For the controller

`def create
      @employee = Employee.create
    if @employee.valid?
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end`

Comment: Ya,. It may be works. I will try like this. Thanks for your response.